# Deploy angular application in Openshift 4

Tags: openshift

I am trying to deploy angular application in openshift. All i have in project is angular project with a dockerfile which does ng build --prod and npm start to start the application. Problem is that I see it running in localhost internally other than the openshift host. Due to this, I get "Application is not available" in browser on hitting openshift url. Please favour on rectifying it.

Below is log from Pod

```
exmaple-ui@0.0.0 start /ng-app
> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200

WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
case.
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2020-02-26T06:08:37.782Z
Hash: dc7eff7d77f7a5fbef4e
Time: 81197ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 285 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 97.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 3.61 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.4 MB [initial] [rendered]
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Can you paste you docker file, service yml, route yml?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest..

1. Build angular app locally or on any CI(Jenkins etc), ng build --prod
2. Use nginx image to deploy and place the static content, nginx config.

2.1 Docker image

```
FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine
## Copy our nginx config
COPY nginx/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/
## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/* && chmod -R 777 /var/log/nginx /var/cache/nginx/ && chmod -R 777 /etc/nginx/* && chmod -R 777 /var/run/ && chmod -R 777 /usr/share/nginx/
## copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY dist/MyApp /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: I didn't have Superuser permission i guess due to which i got "operation not permitted" when i tried it.